# cat and pipe vs. redirection

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, cat

What's the difference between these two commands?

`cat /proc/uptime | awk '{print $1}'`

`< /proc/uptime awk '{print $1}'`

Specifically, how does the second command work? Doesn't the redirection operator `<` has to be accompanied by a command? What does it mean to redirect the contents of a file like that?

Comment: I came across it online and wanted to know how it worked.. there was no explanation backing the usage.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131775/how-long-has-my-linux-system-been-running

Comment: @Goro I don't see anything wrong with the second command. What's wrong about it?

Comment: @JosephSible can you please explain how it works?

Comment: Reading [this comment from Stéphane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325706/cat-gives-different-error-when-opening-non-existing-file/325709#comment572979_325709) made me smarter; thought I’d include it here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, `foo < bar` and `< bar foo` are equivalent in bash scripting. Any time `< filename` is processed by the shell, it means that the command it's associated with will have its standard input come from that file. No extra command or process is involved with this; the shell does it itself.

Running `cat filename` reads the contents of the specified file and writes them to standard output. `|` between two commands means connect standard output of the left command to standard input of the right command.

Thus, both of your commands have the same effect of sending the contents of `/proc/uptime` to awk, but the first way starts an extra `cat` process to do so.

Comment: (warning: snark): see also [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)